# Preference Bundle PSLinkListCell change image

Tags: ios, xcode, jailbreak, tweak

Im trying to write the code for my preference bundle which i added by ticking the 'preference bundle' box when creating my notification center widget on Xcode (iOSOpenDev). I have a `PSLinkListCell` with three items inside it. I would like the three items too change the image in a `UIimage` view depending on the selected choice.

Any help would be much appreciated.

PLIST (only PSLinkListCell)

```xml
  <dict>
        <key>cell</key>
        <string>PSLinkListCell</string>
        <key>defaults</key>
        <string>dylankelly.MyStat</string>
        <key>key</key>
        <string>color_pref</string>
        <key>label</key>
        <string>Background Colour</string>
        <key>detail</key>
        <string>PSListItemsController</string>
        <key>validTitles</key>
        <array>
            <string>Blue</string>
            <string>Green</string>
            <string>Red</string>
        </array>
        <key>validValues</key>
        <array>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <integer>3</integer>
        </array>
        <key>default</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>PostNotification</key>
        <string>dylankelly.MyStat-preferencesChanged</string>
    </dict>
```

UIImage view

```objc
UIImage *bg = [[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"/System/Library/WeeAppPlugins/MyStat.bundle/WeeAppBackground.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:5 topCapHeight:71];
UIImageView *bgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bg];
bgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 312, 71);
```

Comment: please show the (plist) code that defines your `PSLinkListCell`, and probably the code that shows your `UIImageView` that you're using in the widget.

Comment: sorry is that understandable?

Comment: Do you already have a callback handler in your widget's Objective-C code that responds to the `dylankelly.MyStat-preferencesChanged` notification?

Comment: Im sorry i do not know what that is, is that a 
#define PLIST_FILENAME @"/Library/PreferenceLoader/Preferences/MyStat.plist"
  

is it that?

Comment: oh no it's not that is it. Sorry i don't know what that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what you need is for your widget **code** to get notified when the user uses **Settings** (Preferences.app) to change a setting.  Based on the way your plist is setup, it looks like a [Darwin notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFNotificationCenterRef/Reference/reference.html) named

```
dylankelly.MyStat-preferencesChanged
```

will be sent through the Darwin notification center, when the user has changed the setting.  So, you need to register a callback to be invoked when this notification occurs.  As soon as your code is loaded, you should do something like this (for example, in MyWidgetViewController.m, if that's where the image views are managed):

```
#include <notify.h>

...

CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(), //center
                                (void*)self, // observer
                                onPreferencesChanged, // callback
                                CFSTR("dylankelly.MyStat-preferencesChanged"), // event name
                                NULL, // object
                                CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDeliverImmediately);
```

where your callback method (put this in the same MyWidgetViewController.m file) would be:

```
static void onPreferencesChanged(CFNotificationCenterRef center, void *observer, CFStringRef name, const void *object, CFDictionaryRef userInfo) {

    // since this is a static method, we pass the instance in the observer parameter
    MyWidgetViewController* vc = (MyWidgetViewController*)observer;
    [vc updateImage];
}
```

and finally, the code to read the preference plist and update your image view:

```
-(void) updateImage {
    // load the preferences plist file, and read the new color_pref value
    NSDictionary* sharedPrefs = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: PLIST_FILENAME];
    NSNumber* color = (NSNumber*)[sharedPrefs valueForKey: @"color_pref"];
    int colorValue = [color intValue];
    // the integer values correspond to the validValues defined in the 
    //  preference bundle's plist file
    switch (colorValue) {
        case 1:
           bgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"blueBackground"];  // for blueBackground.png / blueBackground@2x.png
           break;
        case 2:
           bgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"greenBackground"];
           break;
        case 3:
           bgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"redBackground"];
           break;
        default:
           break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for you answer! I have updated my code with all of thee above. the images are locates as such


bg.image = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"/System/Library/WeeAppPlugins/MyStat.bundle/WeeAppBackgroundBlue.png"];

Should this be an issue because no background image is showing?

Comment: also where about should the 
CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(),

go?

Comment: @user2196709, as I said in my answer, `CFNotificationCenterAddObserver()` needs to go in your widget code, in a place that runs as soon as possible.  Until that call is made, your widget can't receive notifications.  Because you also need to pass a pointer to the view controller that manages the images (e.g. `self` above), it probably also makes sense to keep this code in the same class that has the callback (`onPreferencesChanged()`) and `updateImage`.

Comment: @user2196709, if `/System/Library/WeeAppPlugins/MyStat.bundle/WeeAppBackgroundBlue.png` is the correct path to your image, and it's not loading, then I'd say that `UIImage imageNamed:` requires relative paths, not absolute ones.  For example `[UIImage imageNamed: @"WeeAppBackgroundBlue"]`.  You normally also want to leave off the .png extension, and let UIKit select between the low and high resolution (Retina) images.

Comment: Thank you for all your help! I have tried the [UIImage imageNamed" "] but still no luck. You said i need to pass a pointer to the view controller that manages the images, is that the .m file? because i only have one of those.

Comment: @user2196709, you're asking a pretty advanced question here (how to use undocumented features to build a jailbreak tweak), but your questions indicate that you're a beginning developer.  Sorry to be blunt, but I don't think I'm going to be able to help you with this one.  Loading a UIImage from your bundle is about the most basic iOS question possible.  How are you doing it now?  You must be setting the background image already, right?  Do it that way, but change the filename.  Or, maybe ask another question here, without all the stuff about plist prefs.  That has nothing to do with images.

Comment: To summarize, it's important to learn to walk before you run.  Take your app/tweak one small step at a time, and have a look at some tutorials.

Comment: I can load the image into the imageView fine, its okay aha, i have tried to look for tutorials about this but i can't seem to find one. Would there be another (easier)  way to have an option on the background image maybe not using the PSLinkListCell? Thanks

Comment: @user2196709, your problem has **nothing** to do with `PSLinkListCells`.  Your problem is that you're having a hard time figuring out how to load a `UIImage` from your bundle (which I notice was your problem in one of your other two questions).  Again, sorry, but I'm going to have to sign off now.